# htaccess multiple parameter values not working properly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, parameters, seo, query-string

**I want to get this URL:**

```
www.example.com/scooter-details/1/vespa-sprint-matt-midnight-blue
```

**But the URL I get is:**

```
www.example.nl/scooter-details/1/Vespa/-Sprint%20-%20Matt%20Midnight%20Blue
```

#### Question

How can I delete all the white spaces `%20` and replace it with hyphen characters `(-)`. Also, is it possible to change the QUERY STRING `Vespa/-Sprint%20-%20Matt%20Midnight%20Blue` to lowercase `vespa/-sprint-matt%20Midnight%20Blue`

#### Here is the `htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# SEO FRIENDLY URL

# Redirect "/scooter-details.php?scooter_id=<num>&scooter_brand<brand>&scooter_model<model>" to "/scooter-details/<num>/<brand>-<model>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^scooter_id=(\d+)&scooter_brand=([^/.]+)&scooter_model=([^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(scooter-details)\.php$ /$1/%1/%2/$2-%3$3 [QSD,L,R=301,NE]
    
# Rewrite /scooter-details/<num>/<brand>-<model>" back to "/scooter-details.php?scooter_id=<num>&scooter_brand<brand>&scooter_model<model>"
RewriteRule ^(scooter-details)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?scooter_id=$2&scooter_brand=$3&scooter_model=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement that redirect in your PHP code rather than in .htaccess.  That type of processing is hard to do in .htaccess, but easy to implement in PHP.  You should remove your `QSD` rewrite rule and its conditions.

So that your PHP script can tell when it should redirect vs when it shouldn't, pass an additional parameter in your last rewrite rule:

```sh
# Rewrite /scooter-details/<num>/<brand>-<model>" back to "/scooter-details.php?scooter_id=<num>&scooter_brand<brand>&scooter_model<model>"
RewriteRule ^(scooter-details)/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?redirect=no&scooter_id=$2&scooter_brand=$3&scooter_model=$4 [L]
```

If your PHP script sees the `redirect=no` parameter, it should produce the page.  If that parameter is missing, it should build the canonical URL and redirect to it.